# How to get SavedRequest in SpringMVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` to force the application redirect to the original URL before login. Now I need to do some custom checks,so I want to get the saved URL from `SavedRequest`.

But when I check the source code at [`SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java),I found the variable is defined as `private`,can someone tell me how to get it?Thanks in advance!

Note:Reflection is not an option and my Spring version is **3.2.6**

```
public class SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    //how to get it in my own code?
    private RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();

   //....
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are doing the checks in the wrong place. What kind of checks do you need to do.

Comment: @M.Deinum I need to do some special check based on the redirect url,if the redirect url matches,then do some check and add some data to the context

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. What context, what data?

Comment: @M.Deinum For example,if the saved url is `testManagement`,but when access this url the program need to read some data from `session`,if it does not have the data,then add the missing session data to it

Comment: Why should this be part of the security chain? Shouldn't this just be a regular filter after the security chain?

Comment: @M.Deinum Hmm,because I think if we access it normally,the session data will always exits,in my application,if we want to access `testManagement`,first we need to click `projectManagement` then the `testManagement` will apppear,and when we access `projectManagement` it will set some session data,however if I use `SavedRequest` it won't,so the problem only occur when using `SavedRequest`

Comment: Which still can be handled properly with a normal filter. Which imho is also the proper way of handling it. That shouldn't be part of the `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` that isn't the thing it is supposed to do for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183879/discussion-between-lucumt-and-m-deinum).

Comment: @M.Deinum I agree with you that a normal filter can do it,but if we use normal filter,**each time when we access the url, the filter will check it**,however in my appication,I just need to check after login success using `SavedRequest`,I do not want to the filter check it everytime

Comment: Which looks like a pre-mature optimization.You only want to check if for a single URL. So instead of doing the wrong thing faster (the role of the  `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` isn't to add stuff to the session), just do the right thing.